# Does Guard Spec. affect accuracy?

Tags: pokemon-series

The item Guard Spec. is supposed to prevent reduction of stats from moves like Growl. Does this also cover accuracy reduction from things like Sand Attack?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Accuracy is a stat which can be reduced by the enemy, so Guard Spec. will protect against accuracy reductions.

Comment: Do you happen to have a source or do you just remember this being the case?

Comment: I looked it up on bulbapedia, but there's no reason to believe it wouldn't.